# how view result date time datediff dateadd , but out-of-range value

Tags: sql, sql-server

[image]

i try compare date now and start date working from master_employee.
but i failed...

if at line i write

```
select @date = date_start 
from Master_Employee 
where id = '2'
```

its succes.
but i hope, can view all result in table Master_Employee.

can you help me ?
thank's very much..

```
DECLARE @date DATETIME
    ,@tmpdate DATETIME
    ,@years INT
    ,@months INT
    ,@days INT

SELECT @date = date_Start
FROM Master_Employee

SELECT @tmpdate = @date

SELECT @years = DATEDIFF(yyyy, @tmpdate, GETDATE()) - CASE 
        WHEN (MONTH(@date) > MONTH(GETDATE()))
            OR (
                MONTH(@date) = MONTH(GETDATE())
                AND DAY(@date) > DAY(GETDATE())
                )
            THEN 1
        ELSE 0
        END

SELECT @tmpdate = DATEADD(yyyy, @years, @tmpdate)

SELECT @months = DATEDIFF(mm, @tmpdate, GETDATE()) - CASE 
        WHEN DAY(@date) > DAY(GETDATE())
            THEN 1
        ELSE 0
        END

SELECT @tmpdate = DATEADD(mm, @months, @tmpdate)

SELECT @days = DATEDIFF(dd, @tmpdate, GETDATE())

SELECT @years AS Years
    ,@months AS Months
    ,@days AS Dayss
    ,GETDATE() AS Date_Now
```

Comment: please post your SQL as text.

Comment: ok i already edit my questions....
btw thank's..

Comment: What exactly you want to achieve?

Comment: i hope can all results...

id_employee = 1
years = 2015
months = 07
days = 06

in my case.. i just can view one result...

Comment: you want to know how many years and months and days for all employees combined, or a separate line for each employee?

Comment: by the way .. thank's very much Daniel..

Comment: yes...i want to know how many years and months and days for all employees.. in my query its works.. but just one result.. if "SELECT date = date_Start FROM Master_Employee" i replace become "SELECT date = date_Start FROM Master_Employee where id = '2' "..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will give you how many days, months, years have passed in aggregate for all employees, As far as I can tell this is what you are tying to do.

```
DECLARE @Today as datetime = CONVERT(Date,GETDATE())

SELECT  SUM(DATEDIFF(day,ISNULL(convert(datetime,@date),Today),@Today)) [Days]
    ,SUM(DATEDIFF(MONTH,ISNULL(convert(datetime,@date),Today),@Today)) [Months]
    ,SUM(DATEDIFF(Year,ISNULL(convert(datetime,@date),Today(,@Today)) [Years]
FROM Master_Employee
```

The reason that

```
SELECT @date = date_Start
FROM Master_Employee
```

is failing is because you are trying to assign all the start dates to the same variable.

If you want separate lines for each employee try:

```
DECLARE @Today as datetime = CONVERT(Date,GETDATE())

SELECT  Id
    ,SUM(DATEDIFF(day,ISNULL(convert(datetime,@date),Today),@Today)) [Days]
    ,SUM(DATEDIFF(MONTH,ISNULL(convert(datetime,@date),Today),@Today)) [Months]
    ,SUM(DATEDIFF(Year,ISNULL(convert(datetime,@date),Today),@Today)) [Years]
FROM Master_Employee
GROUP BY ID
```

Be careful, month and year can be misleading, if the person started `12/31/14` and you ran this on `1/1/15` you will see 1 day, 1 month, 1 year.  You might be better off using only days and figuring your own math for how long that is...

Comment: thank's very much Daniel..
by the way.. tipe variabel date_start is varchar.. how i convert ?

i already your query, n result is "Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.
Warning: Null value is eliminated by an aggregate or other SET operation."

Comment: what version of SQL are you using? What format is `date_start` in?

Comment: see edit, this will give you 0 if the date is blank or an invalid date.

Comment: Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/74258/discussion-between-daniel-e-and-simanisjkt48).